# How to overcome "Conflicting setter definitions for property "?

Tags: json, jackson, swagger, swagger-2.0, fasterxml

I use `com.fasterxml.jackson` and  `io.swagger` libraries. In my REST endpoint I use `org.javamoney.moneta.Money` type for a GET query. When deploying the war i get following exception [1](http://stairs-jumper.livejournal.com/33244.html);

I have followed this [reference](http://stairs-jumper.livejournal.com/33244.html)  and wrote following code[2]; and registered it at @ApplicationPath. But still getting same issue. 
Any guide would be really helpful?

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
@Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(com.test.JsonMoneyProvider.class);
```

[2]

```
import javax.money.CurrencyUnit;
    import javax.money.Monetary;
    import javax.money.MonetaryAmountFactory;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;

    @Provider
    public class JsonMoneyProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
        public JsonMoneyProvider() {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.addMixIn(MonetaryAmountFactory.class, MixIn.class);
            setMapper(mapper);
        }

        public static interface MixIn {
            @JsonIgnore
            @XmlTransient
            MonetaryAmountFactory setCurrency(CurrencyUnit currency);

            @JsonIgnore
            @XmlTransient
            default MonetaryAmountFactory setCurrency(String currencyCode) {
                return setCurrency(Monetary.getCurrency(currencyCode));
            }
        }
    }
```

[1](http://stairs-jumper.livejournal.com/33244.html)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "currency": javax.money.MonetaryAmountFactory#setCurrency(1 params) vs javax.money.MonetaryAmountFactory#setCurrency(1 params)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:293)
        at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:246)
        at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:127)
        at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:99)
        at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:106)
        a
```

Comment: Dont know where exeption comes from, but i thnk there is no point in   `setCurrency(String currencyCode)` implementation Only method (and field) name and signature are used for matching MixIn annotations: access definitions (private, protected, ...) and **method implementations are ignored** http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: @varren i did as mentioned in jackson documentation, but stil getting same issue.  public static interface MixIn {
  At.JsonIgnore
  MonetaryAmountFactory setCurrency(CurrencyUnit currency);

  At.JsonIgnore
  MonetaryAmountFactory setCurrency(String currencyCode);
 }

Answer (score 9):

Simply use this annotation on the deserialization setter method to indicate Jackson wich one to use: [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html)

Comment: The Best answer

Comment: What if the class belongs to a library we do not own?

Comment: @jcflorezr You could extend the class and override the setter method using this annotation on it (as long as you can use that extension in place of that class).